# How to redesign facebook_audience_network plugin to match my flutter app UI?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-layout, flutter-plugin, flutter-android

I use facebook_audience_network plugin to implement native ad in my app. The problem is the layout the plugin provide doesnt go well with my UI as you can see in the picture.

I also tried modifying xml file in plugin's 'layout' folder but it doesn't change the Native ad Layout.

How can I modify the plugin so that the native ad match the other contents?

A snippet of code would be highly appreciated.

My app UI

[image]